# Fancybox is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox

Ok. Here's my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#try1").fancybox();
    });
```

Firebug says "$("#try1").fancybox is not a function".
This is really frustrating!!
It's working fine in other pages. :(

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure your javascriptfiles all get loaded? Check it using FireBug!

Comment: Check that the path js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js is correct .... you may have included it in you html document but it doesn't necessarily mean that the document is in that place. If still doesn't work, provide a link with the issue and we will tell you if the path is correct or not.

Comment: The document is there. I checked it with Firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to recheck the entire HTML page as there are times when certain js files are linked at the bottom of the page, just above the closing body tag.
Hope this helps.

Comment: This is gr8. I was just missing this. I had jquery 1.3.2 linked there. :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if it is properly including the "fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" with firebug?

Comment: what's properly including? and how to check that?

Comment: inspect the html, open the node and check if the code is there

Comment: Well, yes, it's included, I can see that in FireBug!

Comment: it doesn't seem to be loaded, otherwise you wouldn't get that error

Comment: have you included fanybox before jquery files.?

Comment: No, as you can see, first FANCYBOX is included.